# Python/Pandas Dataframe logic on a column with restrictions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Current df

```
ID col1 col2
1  A  1
1  A  2
1  B  3
1  B  4
1  C  5
1  D  6
```

I need to create col3 which will either be 1 or 2 depending on the following conditions:
 col3=1 unless for same ID AND same col1 there are multiple instances of col2. If there are multiple instances, start at the lowest instance of col2 and assign col3=1, then go to the next instance of col2, if next instance is previous instance+1 then col3=2, else col3=1

Sounds confusing but the desired outcome is

```
ID col1 col2 col3
1  A    1    1
1  A    2    2
1  B    3    1
1  B    4    2
1  C    5    1
1  D    6    1
```

EDIT

```
ID col1 col2 col3
1  A    1    1
1  A    2    2
1  A    3    2
1  B    3    1
1  B    4    2
1  B    17   1
1  C    5    1
1  D    6    1
```

Added ID=1, col1=A, col2=3 (since col2 is equal to 1+the row above it), col3=2
Added ID=1, col1=B, col2=17 (since col2 is NOT equal to 1+the row above it), col3=1

Comment: Please show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or maybe

```
df.groupby('col1').col2.apply(lambda x : (x.diff().eq(1))).map({True:2,False:1})
Out[1148]: 
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    1
6    1
7    1
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @babz This is a better solution for your case.

Comment: @Wen, are you familiar with pyspark? I am looking for an analogous solution as this but in pyspark without pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `cumcount`:

```
df.assign(col3 = df.groupby(['ID','col1']).cumcount() + 1)
```

Output:

```
   ID col1  col2  col3
0   1    A     1     1
1   1    A     2     2
2   1    B     3     1
3   1    B     4     2
4   1    C     5     1
5   1    D     6     1
```

#### EDIT to handle "clipping" use df.clip for comparison create new column 'col3a':

```
g = df.groupby(['ID','col1'])['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().fillna(1).ne(1).cumsum())
df.assign(col3a = (df.groupby(['ID','col1',g]).cumcount() + 1).clip(1,2))
```

Output:

```
   ID col1  col2  col3  col3a
0   1    A     1     1      1
1   1    A     2     2      2
2   1    A     3     2      2
3   1    B     3     1      1
4   1    B     4     2      2
5   1    B    17     1      1
6   1    C     5     1      1
7   1    D     6     1      1
```

Comment: thanks @Scott. I suppose this method would fail if there was another row with ID1 col1=A col2=3. Here col3 should equal 2 instead of 3?

Comment: @babz can you create the new dataset with the new row in your question along with expected output.  I am little confused to you question.

Comment: added 2 new cases to the OP